# Using ParallelOptions in Parallel.Foreach for toggling between Serial and Parallel operations

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

We have used Parallel.Foreach extensively in our code, only challenge we had was how to make it serial while using visual debugging in DEBUG mode, following is what we are doing, please share your view:

```
public static class ParallelOptionsWrapper
{
    // Private instance of ParallelOptions 
    private static readonly ParallelOptions @ParallelOptions;

    // Private constructor
    static ParallelOptionsWrapper()
    {
        @ParallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();

#if DEBUG
        // 1 is sequential
        @ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;
#else
        // -1 is unlimited
        @ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1;
#endif
    }

    public static ParallelOptions Instance() { return @ParallelOptions; }
}
```

Following is the usage:

```
Parallel.ForEach(EnumerableList, ParallelOptionsWrapper.Instance(), element =>
{
// Code to run in Parallel
}
```

In this case all the `Parallel.Foreach` callshave same instance of ParallelOptions, which in my view should be fine.

Is this safe? Is this efficient?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Oh! its not clear, in all Parallel Foreach same instance of ParallelOptions get utilized in the current design is that OK

Comment: It is fine, `ParallelOptions` is just a property bag with bunch of properties. That's not a problem. That said, you can return new instances of `ParallelOptions` make make it as a factory method. It doesn't really make much difference.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel thanks for providing a confirmation

Comment: If this is working code and you're looking for a critique, it might be better asked on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I have edited in some questions so that this is no longer a code review but a concrete question.

Comment: That `@` in `@ParallelOptions` is unnecessary and quite distracting.

Comment: This is an incredibly bad idea.  If you need it to debug your code then you parallelized it too soon.  As-is, you blew your chance to debug the *real* problems, those incredibly nasty threading bugs that will cost you weeks of your life to diagnose and repair.  Only using an application setting makes sense.  Consider using the debugger instead, you can freeze threads to diagnose the *occasional* mishap.

Comment: @HansPassant, have I parallelized it too soon? No, this is working piece of code for sometime, but not sure whether it would need debugging in the future, due to database calls in the loop. What you are suggesting is no point doing it this way, use the standard debugger and freeze n-1 threads to get the serial behavior and hence debug it using standard debugger.

Comment: @usr thanks for the edit, it defines the question in much better way, because it was certainly not for Code Review

Comment: @HenkHolterman my bad will be careful, will not use such nomenclature in the future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it safe?

Yes. As long as you don't use cancellation.

> Is this efficient?

Not any more than using separate instances (ie dropping all that `static` stuff).
So it's borderline acceptable but certainly not a good practice.

All you need is :

```
public static ParallelOptions StandardParallelOptions() 
{
        otions = new ParallelOptions();    
#if DEBUG
        // 1 is sequential
        options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;
#else
        // -1 is unlimited
        options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1;
#endif
       return options;   // separate instance for each loop
}
```

This will allow setting a CancellationToken etc.

Comment: Thanks for the good piece of information, as I can understand though I am not cancelling right now, but if I do it will impact all Parallel.Foreach implementation throughout the code, due to using same instance everywhere